# SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_create fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, shibboleth

I'm writing a unit test for a sso session in an application we modified from another campus.  The original application was written using rails 4.1.6.

My unit test is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:shibboleth] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
      :provider => 'shibboleth',
      :uid => '012345678',
      :info => {
        :name => 'Joe User'
      },
      :credentials => {
        :token => 'my_token'
      }
    })
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:shibboleth]
  end

  test "should get create" do
    get :create
    assert_redirected_to root_path
  end

end
```

I have tried the following without success (different error):

```
get :create, :provider => 'shibboleth'
```

My controller is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

    # Confirm user exists in Alma
    if valid_alma_user?(user.uid)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Your user doesn't exist in Alma. (#{user.uid})"
      render :error    
    end    
  end

end
```

My routes file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  # Authentication routes
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

end
```

I'm expecting an assertion that the user is redirected to the root path.

Instead, I'm getting the following.

```
$ bin/rake test test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb
Run options: --seed 27055

# Running:

DEPRECATION WARNING: You did not specify a value for the configuration option `active_support.test_order`. In Rails 5, the default value of this option will change from `:sorted` to `:random`.
To disable this warning and keep the current behavior, you can add the following line to your `config/environments/test.rb`:

  Rails.application.configure do
    config.active_support.test_order = :sorted
  end

Alternatively, you can opt into the future behavior by setting this option to `:random`. (called from <main> at -e:1)
E.

Finished in 0.229031s, 8.7324 runs/s, 13.0987 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
SessionsControllerTest#test_should_get_create:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
    test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:SessionsControllerTest>'

2 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: You have defined `setup` in your RSpec file, but not using it. Any reason?

Comment: When you say "I'm expecting an assertion that the user is redirected to the root path.", does it mean "User is created/found and then redirects to root path"?

Comment: The user should be found in another system and redirected to the main page, or given an error if they are not found..

Comment: I changed "def setup" to "setup do".  Thanks, but no change.

Comment: What i think is happening is that you are trying to find the user for uid "012345678" in `valid_alma_user?` but this must be a test uid only and does not actually exist on "another system". So, it goes into `else` part in the controller. If you want to test the successful login, you need to stub `valid_alma_user?` method in your rspec.